# Scrapy : Parse text between breakpoints

Tags: scrapy

I've come across an HTML like this:

```
<span itemprop="description">
    Colour: Blue
    <br>
    Fabric: Cotton Silk
    <br>
    Type Of Work: Printed
    <br><br>
    Product colour may slightly vary due to photographic lighting sources or your monitor settings.
</span>
```

I want to parse the text between the breakpoints and get them separately. The desired result is something like:

```
["Colour: Blue", "Fabric: Cotton Silk", "Product colour may slightly vary due to photographic lighting sources or your monitor settings."]
```

I've tried

```
response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract()
```

but this gives me the whole text together in a single string.

How can I get it separately around the "
" tag.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it looks like it is working. I made some adjustments to clean the data extracted through the [re()](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions) method:

```
>>> sel.xpath('//span[@itemprop="description"]/text()').re("\s*(.+)\s*")
[u'Colour: Blue', u'Fabric: Cotton Silk', u'Type Of Work: Printed',  u'Product colour may slightly vary due to photographic lighting sources or your monitor settings.']
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: You have replaced the 'extract()' method with 're()', which is still giving me the same output:


`[u'Colour: MulticolouredFabric: CrepeType Of Work: PrintedSize: (Saree- 5.5 meters, Blouse- 0.80 meters)',
 u'Product colour may slightly vary due to photographic lighting sources or your monitor settings. The stitched garment/blouse shown in the image is for presentation purpose only.']`.

It still does not separate the color and fabric.

Comment: can you please share the whole html in a pastebin or the actual URL?

Comment: btw, that `re()` call is just supposed to trim the contents of each item.

Comment: Thanks @stymmjr for clarifying that. My xpath() is working now. It turns out the error was while getting the site HTML.